# JUnit Spring with xml No Annotation failed to load beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

i always getting a null login service in my unit testing,
were using spring with xml configurations and no autowiring.

it got no error in running thru tomcat, aside from junit testing.

i got junit-4.12, hamcrest-library-1.3, hamcrest-core-1.3

heres my sample beans.xml

```
<util:properties location="classpath:user-credentials.properties" id="userCredentials"` />

<bean id="loginServiceBean" class="com.company.service.LoginService">
        <property name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials" />
</bean>
```

in my junit testing

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:WEB-INF/beans.xml")
public class LoginServiceTest {

    private LoginService loginService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {

        User user = createUserModel();
        try {
            loginService.login(user);
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private User createUserModel() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("user");
        user.setPassword("pass");
        return user;
    }

    public LoginService getLoginService() {
        return loginService;
    }

    public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }
}
```

Comment: `loginService` is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing this annotation in your class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

You must tell to junit that it should run with Spring to get the injections working

You should also annote the property loginService with @AutoWired and rename the bean in xml to loginService.

Your atrributes and beans names must be the same for Spring bind it for you!